# My two dimensional array does not want to accept all my data

Tags: c#, arrays

I am giving an array a size by what is contained in the text file. So when I look at my array it shows `[4,7]`. But when I read data into the array it only goes up until `[1,6]`.

Take note that the last name is a position of the data in the array, the other entries then shows a `?` sign and a no-entry sign on the right.

What is wrong with the below code?

```
static void buildArray() 
{
    int rowCount = 0;
    int colCount = 0;
    int placeHolder = 0;
    double devideNumber = 0;
    int tempNumber = 0;
    string typeOptimum;
    string[] objValue;
    string[] constraintValues;
    List<string> testNumbers;
    List<double> ratioList;
    List<double> rhs;


    foreach (string item in constraintsList)
    {
        if (rowCount > 0)
        {
            colCount++;
        }
        rowCount++;
    }

    rowCount = colCount + 1;
    colCount = colCount + 4;
    string[,] arrayConstraints = new string[8, 9];

    //Console.WriteLine("row {0} col {1}", colCount+1, colCount+4);

    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++)
        {
            arrayConstraints[i, j] = "0";
        }
    }

    arrayConstraints[0, 0] = "1";

    objValue = constraintsList[0].Split(' ');
    typeOptimum = objValue[0].ToUpper();
    arrayConstraints[0, 1] = (int.Parse(objValue[1]) * -1).ToString();
    arrayConstraints[0, 2] = (int.Parse(objValue[2]) * -1).ToString();

    for (int i = 1; i < rowCount; i++)
    {
        constraintValues = constraintsList[i].Split(' ');
        arrayConstraints[i, 1] = constraintValues[0];
        arrayConstraints[i, 2] = constraintValues[1];
        arrayConstraints[i, i + 2] = "1";
        arrayConstraints[i, colCount - 1] = constraintValues[3];
    }

    //for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
    //{
    //    Console.WriteLine(" ");
    //    for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++)
    //    {
    //        Console.Write(arrayConstraints[i, j] + "  ");
    //    }
    //}


    do
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(testNumbers[entryPosition]);
        //Console.WriteLine(arrayConstraints[0,entryPosition+1]);
        //Console.WriteLine(entryPosition+1);

        testNumbers = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 1; i < colCount - 1; i++)
        {
            testNumbers.Add(arrayConstraints[0, i]);
        }

        ratioList = new List<double>();
        rhs = new List<double>();

        for (int i = 1; i < rowCount; i++)
        {
            ratioList.Add(double.Parse(arrayConstraints[i, entryPosition + 1]));
            rhs.Add(double.Parse(arrayConstraints[i, colCount - 1]));
        }

        placeHolder = findRatioTest(ratioList, rhs);


        #region multiplyArray

        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
        {
            if (i == placeHolder)
            {
                devideNumber = double.Parse(arrayConstraints[entryPosition + 1, placeHolder]);
                for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++)
                {
                    tempNumber = int.Parse(arrayConstraints[placeHolder, j]);
                    arrayConstraints[placeHolder, j] = (tempNumber / devideNumber).ToString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < colCount; k++)
                {
                    arrayConstraints[i, k] = (double.Parse(arrayConstraints[i, k]) - (double.Parse(arrayConstraints[i, entryPosition + 1])) * double.Parse(arrayConstraints[placeHolder, k])).ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion

        foreach (string item in arrayConstraints)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

    } while (findNumber(typeOptimum, testNumbers) == true);
        //while (findNumber(typeOptimum, testNumbers) == true)
        //{

        //    testNumbers.Clear();
        //    for (int i = 1; i < colCount - 1; i++)
        //    {
        //        testNumbers.Add(arrayConstraints[0, i]);
        //    }
        //} 



}

static Boolean findNumber(string type, List<string> listNumbers) 
{
    Boolean found = false;
    int tempInt, count = 0;

    tempInt = int.Parse(listNumbers[0]);

    if (type == "MIN")
    {
        #region MIN
        foreach (string item in listNumbers)
        {
            count++;
            if (int.Parse(item) > 0 || int.Parse(item)> tempInt)
            {
                entryPosition = count - 1;
                tempInt = int.Parse(item);
                found = true;
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
    else
    {
        #region MAX
        foreach (string item in listNumbers)
        {
            count++;
            if (int.Parse(item) < 0 || int.Parse(item) < tempInt)
            {
                entryPosition = count - 1;
                tempInt = int.Parse(item);
                found = true;
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }



    return (found);

}

static int findRatioTest(List<double> listRatio, List<double> rhs) 
{
    int placeHolder = 0;
    List<double> ratioTest = new List<double>();
    int count = 0;
    double tempSmall;
    int tempPlace = 0;


    foreach (double item in listRatio)
    {
        try
        {
            ratioTest.Add(rhs[count]/ item);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            ratioTest.Add(double.Parse("-1"));
            throw;
        }
        count++;
    }

    count = 0;
    tempSmall = ratioTest[0];
    foreach (double item in ratioTest)
    {
        if (item != 0 && item > 0)
        {
            if (item < tempSmall)
            {
                tempSmall = item;
                tempPlace = count;
            }
        }
        count++;
    }

    placeHolder = tempPlace + 1;
    ratioTest.Clear();
    return (placeHolder);
}
```

Comment: Without seeing your code, we're kind of left to guess.

Comment: I made some changes...

Comment: @LouisMarx `constraintsList` if the loaded file? What is it, an array of all entries cutting empty ones? how are you loading the file to get the `4,7` result? It looks like you're trying to read a CSV file into an array.

Comment: Do you really want this line `rowCount = colCount + 1;`? You may have intended it to be `rowCount = rowCount + 1;`. I don't understand what you're trying to do there though. It seems that colCount will always be equal to rowCount-1 after that loop, except when the constraintList is empty.

Comment: I am trying to get it from a txt file. It uses another class which is called filehandling...

Comment: Yes I would like to keep it like that

Comment: 8 should be rowCount and 9 colCount

Comment: Side note: what is the goal of `double.Parse("-1")`?

Comment: I am trying to devide by a number but when it is 0 it should give the value of -1 to the list... By doing this it doesn't allow the application to devide by 0